# Wrong ELF-class in electron.js

Tags: node.js, electron-packager

I am completely new to electron.js. I am trying to run this code:

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
    
    const createWindow = () => {
        const win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
        });
    
        win.loadFile("index.html");
    };
    
    app.whenReady().then(() => {
        createWindow();
    
        app.on("activate", () => {
            if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
        });
    });

    app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
        if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
    });
```

When I run it, it does open a window and display the contents of the HTML-file correctly. In the console I get a lot warnings though:

```
/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/jan/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so: wrong ELF-class: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel_hasvk.so: wrong ELF-class: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel_hasvk.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF-class: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF-class: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so. Ignoring this JSON
```

Although the code works I feel that I should solve the warnings. I have been on it all day and apart from pointing me to some issue with gcc compiler, neither google nor stackoverflow have helped me so far.